# Difference in between MySQL affected num rows and num rows

Tags: mysql

I am just newbie to the `MySQL`.I want to know what is the main differences in between `mysql num rows` and `mysql affected num rows`?Any example or references will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php):

```
int mysql_num_rows ( resource $result )
```

> Retrieves the number of rows
>   from a result set. This command is only valid for statements like
>   SELECT or SHOW that return an actual result set. To retrieve the
>   number of rows affected by a INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query,
>   use mysql_affected_rows().

And here's [mysql_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php):

```
int mysql_affected_rows ([ resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
```

> Get the number of affected rows by the last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or
>   DELETE query associated with link_identifier.

Notice that the input types are different:  the first wants a result set, from which it counts the number of rows returned; the second wants a db handle.  That makes sense, though, because when you `INSERT` (or `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `REPLACE`) a row, you typically don't want a result set -- you just want to know if it succeeded or failed, or how many rows it updated/replaced/deleted.